# What is the limit of the sequence $(a_n : n \in \mathbb N)$ defined by $a_n = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that the sequence given in the title is convergent and find its limit. I'm not sure if I should use the monotone convergence theorem, because when I try using induction, I don't seem to get anywhere. And I also don't know how to find a suitable candidate for a limit. I do know what the definition of convergence is, though.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

$$0 \leq a_n \leq \frac{\sqrt[n]{n^3}}{n} \to 0 $$

since $\sqrt[n]{n^3}\to 1$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got that? I'm assuming you used the fact that $1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 \leq n^3$. How is this true?

Comment: @Tim $1+2^2+...+n^2 \leq n^2+...+n^2=n \times n^2=n^3,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Comment: Alright, now how did you jump to the fact that $\sqrt[n]{n^3} \rightarrow 1$? I don't quite understand, sorry.

Comment: @Tim...we know that $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$ so $$\sqrt[n]{n^3}=(\sqrt[n]{n})^3 \to 1^3=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$
with non-negative coefficients,
so that
$p(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kn^k
$
with all $a_k \ge 0$,
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} p^{1/n}(n)
=1
$.

Therefore
$\dfrac1{n}p(n)^{1/n}
\to 0$.

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
p(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^d a_kn^k\\
&\le A\sum_{k=0}^d n^k
\qquad A = \max(a_k)\\
&\le A(d+1)n^d\\
\end{array}
$

so
$(p(n))^{1/n}
\le (A(d+1)n^d)^{1/n}
\le (A(d+1))^{1/n}n^{d/n}
$

and all terms of this go to 1.